# block display in css for brfore and after pseudo selectors in a div

Tags: html, css, display

I am having a CSS file with below code:

```
.loader {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

.loader::before, .loader::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background:blue;
    position: absolute;
    /* animation: load .7s infinite alternate ease-in-out; */
}

.loader::before {
    top: 0;
}

.loader::after {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

And the html code is like below:

```
<div class='loader'>Loading</div>
```

The output looks like below:
[image]

But when I comment the display block line in before and after selectors, the output becomes like this:

[image]

I am not getting why the smaller blocks are shifting when I comment display block property. Can someone explain me in naive way please? Been trying to think for past one hour to get complete understanding of this behavior but unable to find proper reasoning about positioning of two smaller block elements with and without block display. Why the after block is not towards left but towards right of 'Loading' text?

The other question is that if we remove display as block, it becomes inline by default, then the three elements should be one after another, but I see first block overlapping in vertical line with the text.

Comment: Please include the HTML on which the included CSS applies. You can provide a [mre] by using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar).

Comment: He has the HTML. It's just a `div` tag. `<div class='loader'>Loading</div>`

Answer (score 1):

`block` holds them on the same block so when you remove it every will align absolutely but if you don't want to use `display: block;` you can simply align them to the `left` or `right`

```css
.loader {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

.loader::before,
.loader::after {
  content: "";
  /*display: block;*/
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  /* animation: load .7s infinite alternate ease-in-out; */
}

.loader::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.loader::after {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='loader'>Loading</div>
```

Comment: what I am still not getting is that if we remove display as block how come the first block is overlapping (in vertical line) with the text. The text should have been after the  first block.

Answer (score 1):

`display: block` causes the element to take up the entire width a "new line".
In this case, both your `before` and `after` squares are taking up their own lines and use up the whole width.

According to [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content):

> The :before and :after pseudo-elements inherit any inheritable properties from the element in the document tree to which they are attached.

[The initial value of the display property is inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) .

Comment: what I am still not getting is that if we remove display as block how come the first block is overlapping (in vertical line) with the text. The text should have been after the  first block.